# Proportionally sized arrows in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Building on ggplot2's [seals example](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_segment.html), I'm trying to change the thickness of arrows so their overall size better reflects the data variable.  I can specify length and thickness, but don't know how to change the size of the arrow-head.  Very grateful for any suggestions.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(grid)

d = seals[sample(1:nrow(seals), 100),]
d$size = sqrt(sqrt(d$delta_long^2 + d$delta_lat^2))

ggplot(d, aes(x = long, y = lat, size = size)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = long + delta_long, yend = lat + delta_lat), arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.1,"cm")))
```

[image]

---

**Edit**

Solution code:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x = long, y = lat, size = size)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = long + delta_long, yend = lat + delta_lat), 
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(d$size/3, "cm"), type='closed')) +
  scale_size(range = c(0, 2))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't say this is a complete solution to your problem, but at least it can be a start.

```
ggplot(d, aes(x = long, y = lat, size = size)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = long + delta_long, yend = lat + delta_lat), 
              arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.7, "cm"))) + 
  scale_size(range = c(1, 2))
```

My changes are minimal: bigger arrow heads and size scale. The upper limit on size scale is the most important if you aim to avoid overplotting.

[image]

From now on, it's probably a good idea to leave only the arrow heads, since the lines are not visible when the size is small. Here's a dirty hack for that:

```
 ggplot(d, aes(x = long, y = lat, size = size)) +
   geom_segment(aes(xend = long + delta_long/100, yend = lat + delta_lat/100), 
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.7,"cm"))) + 
   scale_size(range = c(1, 2))
```

[image]

Of course, it is crucial to keep an appropriate visual relation between big and small values! Otherwise, your plot may become misleading. But that depends on the data, so I cannot give you further advice. Sorry if that's an obvious point.

**UPD:** turns out, unit() function is vectorized, so it comes to the rescue!

```
ggplot(d, aes(x = long, y = lat, size = size)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = long + delta_long/100, yend = lat + delta_lat/100), 
              arrow = arrow(length = unit(d$size * 5,"cm"))) + 
  scale_size(range = c(1, 2))
```

[image]