# geom_segment plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a plot showing different types and magnitudes of change between several types of map categories over time.

I found this thread to be helpful but can't quite get what I want: 
[Proportionally sized arrows in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20656126/proportionally-sized-arrows-in-ggplot)

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
class1  class2  ChangeType ChangeMagnitude
1       2       green       234 
1       3       green       22
2       1       red         171 
2       3       green       144
3       1       red         27
3       2       red         56
```

I want to plot lines with the length of the arrows or size of arrow heads proportional to "ChangeMagnitude" 
and I want the colour of the arrows to vary by ChangeType (e.g., increase = green, decrease =red).

Here is the code I tried:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

ggplot(mydata, aes(x=class1, y=class2)) + geom_segment(aes(xend=type1, yend=type2),data=mydata, colour=mydata$ChangeType, arrow = arrow(length =  unit(mydata$ChangeMagnitude*1, "cm")))
```

The colour argument doesn't work at all and I'm not sure the arrows are giving me what I want. Suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Alternatively, it may be better to use proportional point symbols rather than arrows...

Comment: Put `colour = colour` inside `aes`. `aes()` is the mapping from data to plot, anything outside `aes()` is just constants.

Comment: (Except for the arrow sizes in this case... it's a bit of a hack.)

Comment: @Gregor - Thank you. That fixed the colour problem!